# 2005 Facelift Corsa C - Rumbling/humming sound & others when driving

Tags: vauxhall, corsa

So before I speak to a garage I thought I would ask your opinions here.

I have a 2005 Facelift Vauxhall Corsa C. I've had the brakes and shock absorbers replaced - this was done soon after I bought the car.

Recently I've noticed that if I go full lock when turning I get a knocking sound - putting this down to knackered CV joints.

When driving at any speed over 15mph there is quite a loud rumbling/humming sound inside the car, I mean it is really noticeable, what would you say this is? Possible hub issue or perhaps a wheel bearing?

Also when I go over bumps in the road there is a very loud creaking coming from the front. One idea I had was anti roll bushes needing replacing but not sure, opinions welcomed on this.

There's no doubt I'll be going to a garage to sort this soon but having some idea would be really appreciated :)

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Have you checked the torque on the front (well all really) lug nuts? Loose lugs will give you a lot of the same symptoms you are talking about.

Comment: I haven't yet no, I'll try and take a look this weekend

Comment: Can you take some video and post a link so we can hear what you are describing?

Comment: I'll do that on the way home :) I think it's a wheel bearing, incredibly loud humming

Comment: Definitely a wheel bearing btw, garage fixing it next week :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so DucatiKiller has taken on keeping an eye on this question as I totally forgot to get back to everyone lol. Here's a basic rundown of what's going on with the car and what happened when I took it in for repair:

The loud humming was indeed caused by a damaged wheel bearing, you could also feel the vibrations in the peddles and in the steering wheel - the vibrations would usually be most obvious between 30mph and 50mph.

I took it to the garage and an hour later the N/S/F (Near Side Front) wheel bearing had been changed and now it sounds and drives so much better. Around £48 for parts and £50 for labour costs + the usual 20% VAT here in the UK.

The creaking going over bumps is likely to be wearing wishbones/wishbone bushes and the CV joints are definitely wearing but no need to change them anytime soon.

Hope this info helps anyone in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

OP has indicated that this is a wheel bearing issue.

***Definitely a wheel bearing btw, garage fixing it next week :) – Andy Holmes Mar 19 at 19:41***

***Completely forgot to follow this up. I got it fixed and the car no longer sounds like a jet engine – Andy Holmes 1 hour ago***

Comment: Completely forgot to follow this up. I got it fixed and the car no longer sounds like a jet engine

Comment: lol...awesome.  As well, you can answer the question and award the answer to yourself and share details regarding the resolution.  Thanks.